# Chrome Process Models : Process-per-site-instance and Process-per-site

Tags: google-chrome, browser, process

`Process-per-site-instance` and `Process-per-site` should be understood? I read the explanation here, I feel that there is no difference between the two arguments? It is hoped that God can give some simpler explanations. Examples are better?

`Process-per-site-instance`:
Chromium creates a renderer process for each instance of a site the user visits. This ensures that pages from different sites are rendered independently, and that separate visits to the same site are also isolated from each other. Thus, failures (e.g., renderer crashes) or heavy resource usage in one instance of a site will not affect the rest of the browser. This model is based on both the origin of the content and relationships between tabs that might script each other. As a result, two tabs may display pages that are rendered in the same process, while navigating to a cross-site page in a given tab may switch the tab's rendering process.

`Process-per-site`:Chromium also supports a process model that isolates different sites from each other, but groups all instances of the same site into the same process. This model is based on the origin of the content and not the relationships between tabs.

[link:](https://ahangchen.gitbooks.io/chromium_doc_zh/content/en/General_Architecture/Process_Models.html)

Comment: That document might be somewhat out of date: The new model includes "site isolation", where different origins are kept in separate processes. Try searching for your keywords on https://cs.chromium.org/.

Comment: How to search, I search out the code, and there is no document?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most obvious difference is that under `Process-per-site` mode, it makes sure that each site uses no more than one process, while in `Process-per-site-instance` (which is the default mode) one sites could have more than one processes.

Here is a simple experiment to show the difference:

### Process-per-site-instance

First open the Chromium (I did on Chromium build 778138, I think the result will be the same on any recent Chrome build) in the normal/default mode.

Then open two `github.com` tabs.

Open the Task Manager (under More Tools in Chromium).

[image: two github.com tabs in Process-per-site-instance mode]

As you can see these two tabs have two different process ID `86892` and `86894`

### Process-per-site

Quit Chromium and reopen it with addition argument by running this in the Terminal to enter the process per site mode (I'm using MacOS, for Windows you could follow [this](https://winaero.com/blog/save-memory-in-chrome-by-running-tabs-for-same-site-in-single-process/)):

`open -a "Chromium" --args --process-per-site`

Then open two `github.com` tabs.

Open the Task Manager same as the previous step.

[image: two github.com tabs in Process-per-site mode]

As you can see the two github tabs have the same process ID `86831`

Another interesting observation is that in the first one (`Process-per-site-instance`) the total Memory footprint is around `125 MB` while the second one (`Process-per-site`) is around `88 MB`, which is 30% less! But the downside is, as stated on [Chromuim website](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models):

`(Process-per-site) Can result in large renderer processes. Sites like google.com host a wide variety of applications that may be open concurrently in the browser, all of which would be rendered in the same process. Thus, resource contention and failures in these applications could affect many tabs, making the browser seem less responsive. It is unfortunately hard to identify site boundaries at a finer granularity than the registered domain name without breaking backwards compatibility.`

### Further reading:

In [this article](http://hassansin.github.io/shared-event-loop-among-same-origin-windows) the author did some interesting experiences under the `Process-per-site-instance` mode and I think it could further improve your understanding on the Chrome Process Models.